# Which SQL table contains the users of main site in WordPress multisite?

Tags: sql, wordpress, multisite

I'm looking for the SQL table in WordPress Mutlisite which contains all users of it.

[image: User list in WP Multisite]

When I click on this number, I get the list of users of main site. Where is the table which contain this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is spread over tables `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta`.

`wp_users` contains basic information such as the user login, email, registered datetime and status.

The rest of the information is available in `wp_usermeta`, that uses the classic key/value format of Wordpress.

References:

- https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-database-tables/
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5628/what-are-the-differences-between-wp-users-and-wp-usermeta-tables
- see also [this resource](https://gist.github.com/petenelson/1357af581a0664e052e63275d7a2177f), which provides a handy query to gather user information from both tables

Answer (score 0):

I guess all the information are in the wp_users table and meta information in the wp_usermeta table. But I noticed some users are not visible in the wp_users table when using pmpro registration on a multisite network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33167866)